# Increase maximum height of JComboBox Popupmenu

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, popupmenu

I have a JComboBox with 10 items- When I click on it, the shown popupmenu is not high enough to display all items and shows a vertical scrollbar:

[image]

I wan't the popupmenu to be as high as the content. Is it possible to change the maximum height of that popup menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try

```
yourComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(yourNumber);
```

Here's the javadoc link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setMaximumRowCount(int)